# How to make File Upload with Laravel excel using chunk method?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import, upload

```
public function uploadNotaCorte(Request $request, EstadoRepository $estadoRepository)
{
    $error      = array();
    $path       = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    $notasCorte = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
    })->get();

    $chunk      = $notasCorte->chunk(100);

    foreach ($notasCorte as $key => $notaCorte) {
    //RULES
   }return  $error;
}
```

**
Hi everyone, I'm new to programming and I'm having a hard time implementing the chunk method, so the dodigo above usually works on small files plus larger error files because of the size.
I need to upload a file with 120,000 records and I am trying to use the chunk for this, I do not know what I can do wrong already looked at the documentation more and very simple and I could not solve the problem can anyone help me ??**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `maatwebsite/excel` package, this link should help: http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#chunk

You'll want to change your code to something like this:

```
public function uploadNotaCorte(Request $request, EstadoRepository $estadoRepository)
{
    $error = array();
    $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();

    Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(100, function($results)
    {
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            // RULES
        }
    });

    return  $error;
}
```

This isn't tested and I've never used that package (though good to know it exists) so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I had tried this solution but it did not work in my case James